# jQuery slider with vertical text labels

Tags: html, slider, slide

I'm building a website for a client and I was just wondering if there is any solution that will allow me to create an image slider with what is probably best described as a tab containing a label along the sort side. These tabs need to remain visible whilst the main slide isn't.

Here is a mock up of what I would like it to look at it. You'll have to excuse my poor Paint.NET skills.

[image: mockup of slider]

Slide label 1 would be associated with the current slide, and then when the slides transition 'Slide label 1' might go to where 'Slide label 3' is now etc. Hopefully that makes sense but please let me know if you have any questions.

I would be grateful for any solutions anybody can offer.

Comment: Could you use javascript and jQuery ? If yes, you can use accordion plugin with jQuery

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/rrenula/pen/DGrhf

Comment: 'Accordion'! That's the keyword I was looking for. The code pen example is more what I was thinking of, but it isn't a slider and I need it to slide.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what your are looking for:

http://bqworks.com/accordion-slider/

Comment: Yes, that looks almost exactly what I was thinking of. It is just a shame it isn't free.

Comment: Here is a free version for you: http://www.jqueryscript.net/slideshow/Smooth-Horizontal-Accordion-Slideshow-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

Comment: That looks promising. It doesn't automatically start the slideshow (although it did read like it should) but I'm sure I can manage to implement that bit of jQuery myself if I need to.